# gpaste get as STDIN for youtube-dl

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, ffmpeg, youtube-dl

I'm still fairly new to linux. I've been a user for about 2 months. I understand how to do basic pipings with grep and write `STDOUT` to text files.

I'm trying to do something similar with my clipboard utility `gpaste.` I'd like to use the text that I copy URL info from my gui browser and paste it into a terminal command. The next step would be to learn how to scrape this information automatically and run it through similar manipulations, but let's not get ahead of ourselves.

My process, I open `gpaste ui` and copy the youtube url in question. It gets entered into `gpaste history.` When I enter `gpaste get [#]` the correct entry is returned, great.

However when I attempt to manipulate that data in another application, like youtube-dl, I run into the error "gpaste is not a recognizable url."

Here's what I've tried:

```
youtube-dl | gpaste 0
gpaste get [#] | youtube-dl
```

Not very creative, I know, but what the hey...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure youtube-dl can read from stdin? If so your second example should work.

Try `youtube-dl $(gpaste get [#])`

To make sure *$(gpaste get [#])* returns what you expect you can first do `echo $(gpaste get [#])`

Comment: that worked! Great! Thanks!

So whats the deal with the $()? What am I telling bash whenever I do that?

Comment: @AndÚ   `echo $(whatever commands you want)` means that bash executes whatever is between the (..) and what it returns is used as an argument to echo. So if `whatever commands you want` should print out *Hello AndÚ* the result woud be `echo Hello AndÚ`