# Using regex in BASH script to grab filename/type recently created as output by command earlier in the sequence

Tags: command-line, bash, video, ffmpeg, regex

I recently asked [This question about the use of `gpaste get`output as `STDIN` for youtube-dl](https://superuser.com/q/979684/453189). That question has since then been answered, but I would like to move on to the next step of automation a multi-command task:

1. initate a download of video in the current folder using url copied from url bar in firefox
   command: `youtube-dl $(gpaste get [video url])`
2. convert the mkv or mp4 or m4a file to a .wav
   command: `ffmpeg -i [filename of video from step one].<filetype of video from step one>   [filename of video from step one].wav`
3. [...process continues...]

My question is: I am still new to regex. Is there a regex sequence that I can employ to grab the filename from the file created by the `youtube-dl` command and use it as the input for the following `ffmpeg` command?

Here’s an example:

```
gpaste get 0
```

returns `https://somevideo.com/video`

```
youtube-dl $(gpaste get 0)
```

Downloads file to current folder with `Y` filename &&

```
ffmpeg -i <filename Y>
```

Will return a duplicate of the initial file, now in `.wav` format

How can I get tell bash to get that filename Y before it exists, so that I can put all of this into a script?

Would I also need to filter according to a range of filetypes (all video types) or would I filter for most recent file in the current folder or a combination of both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checked documentation of youtube-dl, it accepts this parameter:

```
--get-filename                   Simulate, quiet but print output filename
```

So, maybe you can try something like this:

```
videourl=$(gpaste get [video url])
videofilename=$(youtube-dl --get-filename $videourl)
youtube-dl $videourl
#further processing.
```

Comment: I remember seeing this parameter in the man pages, but I had no idea how I could use it. Your solution makes total sense, just set it as a variable then call it in the next command of the sequence, am I right?

Comment: @AndÚ, exactly.